# Angular not removing json prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have an HTTP request that looks like this in angular js

```
$http.get('appTop/appTop.json').then(function successCallback(response) {
    top.list=angular.fromJson(response.data);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

top.list is defined elsewhere and the file being requested does exist but every time i run the request it returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )                    angular.js 12520
```

What is causing this error? Since it's coming from within angular.js, I can't figure out what is wrong.

Just in case it is relevant, my scripts load in this order:

- jquery
- jquery mobile
- angular.js
- angular-touch.js

I have not altered the angular.js file in any way, and I am loading it using the angular.min.js file.

For a server, I'm using a locally hosted Node.js server.

It has come to my attention that it may be in part because of my JSON file, so here is it:

```
)]}',
[{
    "page": "/main/main.html",
    "title": "Home"
}, {
    "page": "/server/server.html",
    "title": "Server"
}]
```

the starting `)]}'`, is recommended by [angular for security reasons](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection)

Update

The error seems to be because angular is not removing the recommended prefix. Can anyone see why? I updated the code snippets according to the Input I got already and it's still not parsing it correctly.

Comment: Have you verified that the content in `appTop.json` is valid JSON? You can try using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: i just checked and it is valid json with the angular recommended prefix )]}',\n

Comment: if i remove the angular recommended prefix it returns a syntax error with a p rather than a ) p is the first character that isnt a [ or {

Comment: see the latest update it is still returning the error for the )

Comment: with the fixed json it doesnt give the error if i remove the prefix but angular is suppose to remove the prefix first correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to deserialize the Json that you are receiving.

```
$http.get('appTop/appTop.json')
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        top.list = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The `response.data` part may just need to be `response`. It depends on how you are receiving the response.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: this seems like the right answer but it is still giving me that error

Comment: is it new to the 1.5 build? i was trying to use the latest stable build which is 1.4.8

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you if it is new or not. I have just always had to use it when retrieving Json.

Comment: It isn't new to the build I just checked

Comment: Sorry I do not have the full explanation. I'm also not at my computer so it is a little harder to mess around with things. I hope it at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for you're input that was helpful